# Why new Base() cannot be passed to <? extends Base>?

Tags: java, generics

This code:

```
public class Base<E> {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Base<? extends Base> compound = new Base<Base>();
        compound.method(new Base()); 
    }                // ^ error
    void method(E e) { }
}
```

Gives such compilation error:

```
Error:(4, 17) java: method method in class Base<E> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: capture#1 of ? extends Base
  found: Base
  reason: actual argument Base cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Base by method invocation conversion
```

From what I understand, `E` becomes `? extends Base`, something that extends `Base`. So, why `new Base()` can't be passed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Base<? extends Base> compound` means that `compound` is parameterized with some subtype of `Base`, but you don't know which one. If the parameter type is unknown, then the compiler can't check that `new Base()` matches that type.

`E` does become `? extends Base` You might think that the method would accept *any* subtype of `Base`, but it doesn't. It only accepts one *specific but unknown* subtype of `Base`.

So you can't call any method that takes `E` as a parameter, but you can call a method that returns `E`.

Allowing your example to compile would lead to type-safety errors like:

```
List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(new Object()); // Error - Can't add object to list of Strings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to define your method as a generic:

```
<E> void method(E e) { }
```

Note the the addition of the `<E>`.

This fixed the compilation error for me.  Although, I would have expected the parameter you supplied at class-level to have applied.

Comment: With `<E>` before method any object can be passed :) But, my question is not how to make it compile. I'm kindly asking for an explanation why it doesn't compile :)